# Android clipborad which stores multiple texts

Tags: gratis, android, clipboard

I am bascially looking for [Ditto](http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/) for Andoid.

- gratis
- can store multiple texts
- plus boilerplate
- let's me edit & delete them
- and search through them

Please don't just Goole, or search Izzy's site - I can do that - recommend me soemthign which you yourself use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I myself use [Clip Stack ✓ Clipboard Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.catchingnow.tinyclipboardmanager). Features:

- free,
- open source ([available from F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=com.catchingnow.tinyclipboardmanager)),
- stores the clipboard history also if the phone reboots,
- the 5 most recent texts are accessible in the notification,
- allows editing and deleting,
- search feature.